# recursive calling of function - send deep copy of dict without an element

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have a dictionary called **traversal**. For given key, I have array of values. I want to recursively call function traverse as many times as many values I have in this array, each time deleting one of them.

So far I have this:

```
for i in xrange(0,length-1,1):
    print ("try branch with value: " + next + " and index " + str(i))

    next=(traversal[key])[i]
    result=result+key[i]

    #here you need to remove next from traversal
    traverse(100,result,copy.deepcopy(traversal),next)
```

However, I need to modify it so that instead of deep copy of dictionary **traversal**, I would be sending the deep copy of the dictionary without one of the values. Something like this:

```
traverse(100,result,copy.deepcopy(del (traversal[key])[i]),next)
```

Any advice how to write this?

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Comment: How would you know how to stop? Recursive functions need a conditional statement that tells it that it is finished.

Comment: At each step of recursion I want to delete one element from dictionary named traversal. When traversal is empty, I have "return" in the code.

Comment: General rule of thumb is not to modify a dictionary while iterating (in your case recursing through it). Python has many safegaurds to prevent you from doing so. You might want to make a copy of the dict first then iterate the original dict and modify the copy. This way you copy only 1x (copy is an expensive function) and you won't run into any dictionary errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dictionary values are sequences and you are *sequentially* iterating over those sequences.  After making the copy, you can remove the element from the copy's value with a slice.

```
>>> d
{1: [1, 2, 3]}
>>> e = copy.deepcopy(d)
>>> e
{1: [1, 2, 3]}
>>> i = 0
>>> key = 1
>>> v = e[key]
>>> v = v[:i] + v[i+1:]
>>> e[key] = v
>>> e
{1: [2, 3]}
>>> d
{1: [1, 2, 3]}
>>>
```

Without seeing more of the code or data, it is hard to tell if this is what you really want or need.